# Java proxy configuration java.net.Authenticator

Tags: java, http, proxy, jvm

I have a hard time trying to setup my proxy settings through the jvm commands

For example I use JVM arguements like

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=my.proxy.net
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyUser=myusername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword
```

But I am unsuccessful

However If I proceed through code using the java.net.Authenticator it works

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication("myusername", "mypassword");
  }
});
```

Is there any way to stick to the JVM arguements and avoid using an authenticator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=myusername
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypassword
```

These are not system properties recognized by the JRE. They belong to some external package, possibly the Apache HTTP Client.